# Convert 100k row pyspark df to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a pyspark df with 100k rows. I am using spark

```
df = pandas_df.toPandas()
```

which takes lot of time to execute this syntax. Is there any other way to do this operation within seconds?
Also to save the pyspark dataframe in `.csv` format it takes lot of time. Why is it so?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html

Comment: 1 lakh is 100k right? that's tiny for PySpark do you get any warnings when you run the `.toPandas()` method?

Comment: @Manakin code lines gets executed within few minutes but converting dataframe to pandas takes approx an hour. Yes its 100k and I donot get any warning

Answer (score 0):

Try to repartition your datafram first before converting to pandas df

```
df = df.repartition(1)
df = df.toPandas()
```

Comment: This is not working with the dataframe. dataframe' object has no attribute 'repartition. I guess it works for RDD.

Comment: It should be .. Please check if that is a Pandas DF or a spark DF